# systemd: how to start a tomcat service after a successful tomcat service start

Tags: linux, tomcat, systemd, systemctl

I have two tomcat servers. I want with systemd to have tomcatB started only if tomcatA was successfully started.

e.g. tomcatB service should start right after "org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup" is logged in catalina.out log file. Is that possible?

Comment: Questions specific to `systemd` are more appropriate to be asked on http://serverfault.com, http://unix.stackexchange.com or if they are Ubuntu-specific http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using both [`After=` and `Requires=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Before=) in the unit file for `tomcatB` to specify that it depends on `A` and should start after it.